# JWST - coordinates of each of the 18 mirror segments?

Tags: design, james-webb-telescope

I am curious about the relative orientations and locations of each of the JWST’s 18 hexagonal mirrors, when they are in place.

The unfortunate (and subsequently corrected) problem with Hubble’s primary mirror brought the issue of mirror tolerances to the world’s attention.

Clearly, 18 segments, each with its own seven actuators(1) (each with incredible precision and a remarkable range), is part of the JWST’s solution to this real (potential) problem.

Because there is talk in the popular press of nanometer precision in these actuators, I am interested in the actual (designed) (precise) locations of these mirrors.

Can someone do the math on this? Say, for example, find the coordinates of the center, and each corner (6), of each segment, when all are in their focused, final positions … all in a common coordinate system? (For extra credit, provide some information on tolerances of these positions).

(Sort of a math problem, I know, but also JWST specific, and part of the current deployment and calibration process.)

—-

(1) edited from “1” to “7” actuators per segment, per comment from Uwe.

Comment: Each segments has not only one own actuator, it has seven.

Comment: @Bruce S: check out the following

Comment: sorry... cannot get the links to post.  three good papers from the folks who designed/built/tested system.  really cool engineering (no pun intended)

Comment: https://www.esmats.eu/amspapers/pastpapers/pdfs/2006/warden.pdf is a good place to start.

Comment: https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/7439/743916/Cryogenic-radius-of-curvature-matching-for-the-JWST-primary-mirror/10.1117/12.845115.full

https://www.spacefoundation.org/tech_track_papers/radius-of-curvature-matching-system-for-a-space-based-segmented-telescope/

Comment: Someone should make it into a complete answer - I don't have the sources at hand, but... the coordinates are just an intermediate tool of minor significance in the process. The calibration is performed iteratively: take a photo of a distant star, tweak the mirror to make the image of the star centered (overlaid) with images of other mirrors, sharp and without distortions. Repeat.

Comment: Coordinates have a role in estimating by how much the actuators should move to improve the image, but neither do the mirrors have a fixed, firm "origin" coordinate to move **relative to** (just relative to current, whatever "current" is) nor a fixed firm "increment/unit" on their coordinates to move **by a fixed distance**, to achieve perfect precision, (just an estimate that improves the precision.) It's all a dynamic feedback loop, not dependent on absolute units and absolute positions.

Comment: @Bruce S the real magic of the primary mirror tuning is not in the rough 'physically measurable' positioning but rather the nano-positioning and curvature tweaking to achieve infra-red wavefront consistency across all 18 mirror segments. This results in wave additions instead of wave cancellations. The mere act of getting the mirrors pointed to the same place is relatively easy.